# Error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "src/assets/" directory does not exist.'

Tags: php, symfony, bolt-cms

Getting this strange error when accessing the backend in bolt. I haven't deleted this particular directory, and the frontent works fine.

```
Stack trace:
#0 src/Render.php(53): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->addPath('/var/www/html/h...')
#1 src/Application.php(607): Bolt\Render->render('error.twig', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Bolt\Application->errorHandler(Object(Twig_Error_Loader), 500)
#3 vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/ExceptionListenerWrapper.php(52): call_user_func(Array, Object(Twig_Error_Loader), 500)
#4 [internal function]: Silex\ExceptionListenerWrapper->__invoke(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#5 vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Object(Silex\ExceptionListenerWrapper), Object(Sym
File: vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
Line: 93
```

Comment: I had the same problem deleting an empty views folder. Try clearing the cache and if that doesn't help create the folder you deleted.